# Modifying a data file remaining not duplicate in python

Tags: python, text, duplicates

If there is a file like

```
1
1
5
3
3
45
45
87
6
6
4
```

I would like to store only not duplicate values like,

```
5
87
4
```

Any comments appreciated.

Comment: I have thought that reading line by line of the file. However, I do not know how to read the next row. I have try this "print [key for key, group in groupby(x) if len(list(group)) < 2].

Comment: But this is ok for only for the short rows. I can copy and paste the data file into the code. If I have large rows in a data file. I don't know how to deal with this.

Comment: if you aim just to get uniq data, you may also get it directly using sort and uniq commands :                    sort filename.txt | uniq -u – Archit Jain 6 mins ago

Comment: "sort filename.txt | uniq -u > out.txt" <- this is the perfect solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment, Seems like you are not able to read file and get data. YOu may use following code for that:

```
x=open("filename.txt").readlines()
```

And then you can use your code:

```
print [key for key, group in groupby(x) if len(list(group)) < 2]
```